# Web Deploy + EF Migrations in a TeamCity Build

Tags: asp.net, teamcity, webdeploy

I can do each of these separately, but I can't figure out how to make them work together.

In my ASP.NET build on TeamCity, I am using Web Deploy to deploy to my production server. After deploy, I want to run EF Migrations from TeamCity. I have been doing this by calling the following script:

> migrate.exe MyProject.Data /startUpConfigurationFile:..\web.config

Where `MyProject.Data` contains my Data Context and the web.config containing my connection string. However, I am also using web.config transformations, and since I just started using Web Deploy the web.config file on the build server hasn't had config transformations applied.

Is there a way I can either force web.config transformations to run, or to determine what the connection string should be based on the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://ctt.codeplex.com/) tool and modified my EF Migrations step to the following:

```
ctt.exe s:..\web.config t:..\web.TeamCity-Test.config d:..\migrations.config
migrate.exe MyProject.Data /startUpConfigurationFile:..\migrations.config
```

Answer (score 0):

Also transformed Web.config file could be found in folder

```
%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\PROJECT_NAME\obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\
```